# How hide a webpart feature in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, video

Hello I would like to know how I can hide green line . The web part i’m using is content editor.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the HTML from Content Editor Web Part

Comment: <iframe width=640 height=360 src='https://chId=6b7a580c%2Dd21b%2D4264%2Da60e%2D59a72bb34087&amp;vId=75208af4%2D8968%2D4cf1%2Db3c8%2D8fcab0b015e1&amp;width=640&amp;height=360&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;showInfo=true' allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Please add me over Skype will try to guide you how to hide that line. You can check my profile for Skype ID